# i try to install flask on my windows cmd and i got UnicodeDecodeError when installing MarkupSafe module

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, pip

i try to install flask on my windows cmd and i got UnicodeDecodeError when installing MarkupSafe module

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 73, in console_to_str
    return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 5: invalid continuation byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
   status = self.run(options, args)
 File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
   prefix=options.prefix_path,
 File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
   **kwargs
 File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 878, in install
   spinner=spinner,
 File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 676, in call_subprocess
   line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())
 File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 75, in console_to_str
   return s.decode('utf_8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 5: invalid continuation byte
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is from a missing wheel for MarkupSafe on Pypi. Here is the workaround (git-bash on Windows):

```
git clone git@github.com:pallets/markupsafe.git /c/tmp/markupsafe
cd /c/tmp/markupsafe
./setup.py bdist_wheel
The result is a valid wheel: /c/tmp/markupsafe/dist/MarkupSafe-1.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl.
```

In your other project where you need to use it, simply call

```
pip install /c/tmp/markupsafe/dist/MarkupSafe-1.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```